# Calling TypeScript compiled code from html in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, typescript

I am new to NodeJS and am trying to learn TypeScript.

While following Microsoft's [TypeScript-Node-Starter](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-Node-Starter), I have a question about how the app is working.

What I understand:

1. All `ts` files under [`src`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-Node-Starter/blob/master/tsconfig.json#L20) are compiled into `js` files under [`dist`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-Node-Starter/blob/master/tsconfig.json#L10).
2. [This](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-Node-Starter/blob/master/src/app.ts) is the app's [starting point](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-Node-Starter/blob/master/package.json#L14).
3. The static files are served from the folder [`src/public`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-Node-Starter/blob/master/src/app.ts#L80-L82).
4. In this html (or pug) file, the page would try to load `main.js` script from the folder `src/public/js`.

Now my question is: how does the html know to load `main.js` from `dist/public/js` rather than `src/public/js`? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. correct. You can see why it's `src/` to `dist/` and a few other details regarding TypeScript-to-JavaScript in `tsconfig.json` (TypeScript expects this file to exist and declare all these things - see here for [details](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html)).
2. wrong, but it's kind of tricky. Node here isn't run directly since it doesn't declare an entry point in `package.json`. Instead, this file declares a `script.start` command that is called when typing directly `npm start`, which executes `npm run serve`, which is declared to execute `node dist/server.js`. Conclusion: your entry point is `server`, not `app`.
3. wrong: [`__dirname`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/modules.html#modules_dirname) is a variable always available in a file, and it contains - at runtime - the path of this file's directory. Since your file in `src/` is converted to a file in `dist/` and executed there, the actual files being served are in `dist/public`. Have a look at `package.json` for its command `build` (hint: there's something about copying static assets, and another about building Sass).
4. wrong as per point 3, correct otherwise.

Now you should have the answer to your question. ;)

Comment: I added a file as in the project to copy static assets with the following line:
`shell.cp("-R", "src/public/css", "dist/public/");` to copy the css files since I was not using `scss`. `js` files are created with `tsc`.

Thanks a lot!